# Which library to use for cryptographic functions

Tags: haskell, cryptography, libraries

> Note: this is not asking for a personal viewpoint on what is the better library, but rather what is the "safest" library or what is a good indication of a "safe" library.

I was looking for a Haskell library with AES256 encryption/decryption capabilities and found quite a few.

- [cryptocipher](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptocipher)
- [cryptonite](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite)
- [AES](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/AES)

The problem is that most of these seem abandoned, except cryptonite who again seems like the least popular library (the one with the least amount of downloads).

I was wondering if using a library that seems outdated could be a problem (should I worry about possible security flaws, etc.) or if I should simply go with the one that seems most popular?

Comment: Without any criteria for assessment, this question is utterly useless. If the criteria is activity, then you've answered the question yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd definitely recommend cryptonite. It's a newer library consolidating a number of older libraries, and the ecosystem hasn't moved over yet.

Comment: That was what I was thinking, however cryptonite doesn't seem to have any production-ready versions.

Comment: @NatureShade Define "production-ready"